# Leaflet filled contour map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, web-mapping, contour

I have evaluated the Getis-Ord Gi*-spatial statistic for each point in my map. Like this, each point is assigned a Gi-score and due to this a certain color, as you can see in the image below.

What I would like to do now is to group points of the same color and make them appear as an area of that color, similar to the second image.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [turf.js isobands function](http://turfjs.org/examples/turf-isobands/).

Though ultimately @Diffusion_net is right: trying to do this in the browser is going to be much harder than doing it on your own using Arc/qGIS.  If your data is relatively static, this shouldn't be an issue.  If you have to perform these calculations on the fly in the browser, then isobands should get you there.

Answer (score 0):

So I do not know of any native plug ins for leaflet to create contour lines and fill them in like this. So unless you want to write your own function for achieving this I see the easiest way to go about this would be to create contour polygons(filled contour lines) in a desktop software (ArcGIS, QGIS, etc.)and export the shapefile, afterwards convert that into a polygon layer/s for importing into leaflet.Then with css or leaflet properties change colors to what you please.

Best of luck!